# Download mp3 and save it as string

Tags: android, audio, encoding

I am trying to download an mp3 file with download manager using the following code

```
try {
    URL url = new URL(VIDURL);
    URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
    connection.connect();

    // Detect the file length
    int fileLength = connection.getContentLength();

    /* ......Download Manager...... */
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(VIDURL);

    // Download Manager Request
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir("/Android/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/", extractLastWord(VIDURL));
    long ID = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
    downloadId = ID;
    db_obj.DetailsInsertion(extractLastWord(VIDURL), ID + "");
    try {
        mythread.destroy();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        callNewThread();
    }

} catch (Exception e) {
    // Error Log
    Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here the file saving with `filename.mp3` format, Once the download finish I am  encrypting the data and saving the file so that user open it. My problem is user can open it and use during  downloading. Is there anyway I can save the file in any other way as string or something and then convert it.

Comment: convert it to base64

Comment: from where exactly

Comment: If you can get data in bytes ,you can do this for converting to string Base64.encodeToString(bytes, 0);

Comment: Thats the problem I am unable to retrieve it as byte array

Comment: Download as media/file from url in async or smthng when download finish then encrypt it

Comment: Without using download manager ?

Comment: Download it to your applications private directory, and only move it to the public directory after you have encrypted it.

Comment: thats what I am doing.. but still they are pointing out the chance for happening it

Comment: Save it using different extension .gth something so they cant play it

Comment: ow..yes but when we click on it a list of options is loading and audio is there.. :(

Comment: you trying without download manager right

Comment: no its with download manager..

Comment: Download with async task so user not able to know song is downloading.you can finish ur task